# IcCube - Using Perpectives

Tags: perspective, iccube

I have a schema and a report using this schema. Now I would like to show in this report different parts of my data to different roles (e.g. different partner shops should only see the data concerning them). For that I made one perspective for every partner and gave each of them a different role using only this perspective.
The report itself I set up to use the whole cube.

But apparently this is not working, as I thought, since they can all see the whole cube.

Did I miss something?
Is it even possible, what I try to achieve?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise using the authorization instead of the perspectives to limit roles access ( [access rights](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/security/access_rights.php) ). You can still keep the perspectives if it's not possible with the authorization.

If you need to use perspectives, you can setup cube/perspective access right per role.

If this does not work, contact support directly (not easy without the schema to understand the problem)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I didn't understand the perspectives correctly. I thought, for the limiting, you qould have to have a perspective in addition to the right role setup. But now I tried it with allowing only [shop].[some_shop] in the facts of the right cube in the role definition and it works :)

Comment: in MDX hidden attributes (dimensions, cubes, measures) are not visible but are still accessible. You can still use them in a hardcored MDX. It's best to use security if you wan't to forbid their usage.